# Dude with taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, polynomials

Good night, i'm working with an problem of polynomial taylor, but i have a problem with the residue.

Get a quadratic approximation $f\left(x,y\right)=\sin\left(x\right)\sin\left(y\right)$
  near the origin.
How accurate is the approximation if $\mid x\mid\leq0.1$ and $\mid y\mid\leq0.1$ ?

My work in the problem:

$f\left(x,y\right)=\sin\left(x\right)\sin\left(y\right)$

$f\left(x,y\right)\thickapprox f\left(0,0\right)+xf_{x}+yf_{y}+\frac{1}{2}\left(x^{2}f_{xx}+2xyf_{xy}+y^{2}f_{yy}\right)+R$

$f(x,y)\thickapprox xy+R$

but i cannot solve $R$ $<- Residue$

Comment: Should those be $x f_x$ and $y f_y$ instead of $xf$ and $yf$?

Comment: Yesss!!! sorry.... THANKS @JuanSebastianLozano

Comment: Dude... woah! Taylor! [insert a Conspiracy Keanu, or any Bill and Ted meme here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quadratic approximation will usually get worse the further out that you go, and so the $R$ term will only get bigger. This is because $R = f(x,y) - \hat{f}(x,y)$, where $\hat{f}$ is the quadratic approximation (this is not standard notation). Therefore if $|x-x_0|,|y-y_0| \leq \epsilon$ then $|R| \leq |f(\epsilon + x_0,\epsilon + y_0)-\hat{f}(\epsilon + x_0,\epsilon + y_0)|$

In your case it would be that $|R| \leq \approx .00003$

Comment: sorry but i don't know, what's $\hat{f}(x,y)$ for you?

Comment: Like I said, its the quadratic approximation, meaning it's the 2nd order taylor expansion without the remainder term. In this case, its $\hat{f}(x,y)=xy$.

Comment: I think that perhaps a key point here is that $f(x,y) \approx \hat{f}(x,y)$, but you add the $R$ term to make it equal: $f(x,y) = \hat{f}(x,y) +R$ because $R$ is the higher order taylor terms that when added to the first two terms converge to the function.